# jQuery UI selectmenu on iPad doesn't properly close when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI to generate a selectmenu. It works well on the desktop, but it's having a weird behavior on the iPad when trying to close it. On the site I'm working on, clicking anywhere outside the box/dropdown list will NOT close it except if I click in the area to the left of the box.

The code is pretty basic. HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Slower</option>
    <option>Slow</option>
    <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
    <option>Fast</option>
    <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("select").selectmenu();
```

CSS:

```
.ui-selectmenu-button{
    font-size:16px!important;   
    height:35px;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-image:none;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

I've create a Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/8fwcms5v/1

The behavior is not quite the same as on my site. But you will see that clicking anywhere above the select (when it's open) does not close it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/medinasod/pen/eJebmQ)

```
$("select").selectmenu();

$("html").bind("click touchstart",function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.className)
  if (e.target.className === "ui-selectmenu-text" ||
    e.target.className === "ui-menu-item" || e.target.className === "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s") {
    return;
  } else {
    $("select").selectmenu("close");
  }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to include the image for the down arrow. Your code works pretty well, but now clicking on the arrow won't open the list. Here is my updated demo with the image and your code: https://jsfiddle.net/8fwcms5v/31/

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue. Clicking the arrow icon doesn't open the list with or without the code I provided. How did you add the triangle?

Comment: I simply added the path to the image in the CSS but the placeholder for it  was already there (<span class="ui-icon ...). In your DEMO, if you click on the area where the image should be located, you won't be able to open the list. In my original jsfiddle however (ie, before adding your code), the list does open when clicking in this area.